# How to convert an NSArray from Obj-C to Array in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, nsarray

Yes, I know the title seems a bit to obvious, and can easily be searched for the solution. I know how to convert a 1-D `NSArray` to an `Array`, that is simple enough.

However, that is not my issue, as my NSArray is different. Please see the following code

```
NSArray *artists;

artists = @[@"Performed by: Legendary Group", @"Performed by: Ivan Cheong",
          @"Performed by: Tien Nguyen", @"", @[@"Performed by: DJ Happee From 
            Channel 3.3", @"Performed by: Adam Cease", @""], 
            @"Performed by: Music Between California and Summer", @""];
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I was about to access it like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    if ( [ [artists[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                isEqualToString:@""] )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

As you can clearly see, my NSArray contains another array at index 4. I require this for trivial purposes.

I would like to know is it possible to convert my `NSArray` to a Swift standard `Array` type?

I have tried to implement the equivalent:

```
var temp = NSArray()

let artists = ["Performed by: Legendary Group", "Performed by: Ivan Cheong",   
           "Performed by: Tien Nguyen", "", ["Performed by: DJ Happee From 
        Channel 3.3", "Performed by: Adam Cease", ""], "Performed by: Music 
             Between California and Summer", ""]

temp = artists
```

This works properly as I want, however, this is not up to Swift 2.0's coding standards.

I want to use an `Array`, but I don't know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of AnyObjects:

```
let artists: [AnyObject] = ["Performed by: Legendary Group", "Performed by: Ivan Cheong",
    "Performed by: Tien Nguyen", "", ["Performed by: DJ Happee From Channel 3.3", "Performed by: Adam Cease", ""], "Performed by: Music Between California and Summer", ""]
```

Then check the type of each item in your tableView function and handle accordingly:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch artists.indexPath {
        case is String: //handle string
        case is NSArray: //handle array
        default: //trap other stuff


        }
       }
```

Comment: Please see how I initialized the NSArray `artists` carefully. I have defined an array within an array, and I am having trouble translating "that" array to Swift. It would be easy for me to translate it to Swift if it was a 1-D array,  as you have shown, but it's not 1-D. I have updated my question for clarity.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you have an array in an array here. Can you explain?

Comment: I use it to display a schedule of events, however, that is irrelevant to my issue.

Comment: Edited to address your issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no way to directly achieve this with `Array` type conversion?

Comment: As I understand it, Array is a struct; NSArray is an object. I believe once you create an array of anyobjects, as you are doing here, the elements need to be objects, so Array automatically becomes an NSArray.